# How to use the value of a hash in a variable constructed from another variable value

Tags: perl

I read some configuration from a file called flowfx.config.pl.
It looks like this:

```
logfile_path     => '/proj/flowfx/ffx/log/',
path       => '/temp/',
skip_files => [ 'png', 'gif', 'jpg' ],
```

I then want to use a component passed in from the command line and construct a variable
which uses the value of path from the config file. It works to a certain extent. It's easier to show you the code and for you to read the comments to explain what does and does not work.

```
my %flowfx = do 'flowfx.config.pl';

#prints value of '/proj/flowfx/ffx/log/'
print $flowfx{logfile_path};


#my component name which will be passed in on command line. hardcoded for the moment
$component = "flowfx";
```

Next section of code works fine. $flowfx_log has a value of '/proj/flowfx/ffx/log/' and is printed as such.

```
${$component . "_log"} =   $flowfx{logfile_path};
print ${$component . "_log"};
```

Below doesn't work. I get error of "Use of uninitialized value in print"
I want $flowfx_log2 to have the value of $flowfx{logfile_path} which is '/proj/flowfx/ffx/log/'

```
${$component . "_log2"} =   ${$component."{logfile_path}"};
print ${$component . "_log2"};
```

I'm sure it's something trivial. Can you give me some hints on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't create named scalar variables using strings, its a bad idea. Use a hash instead, it is what they are there for, and it is actually in every way a better idea.

Comment: Also, using `do` to read in a configuration file is a horrible idea. There are much better ways to serialize data. You're executing arbitrary code to read in a few values.

Comment: Yeah I know. only limited to certain modules on the server though, otherwise I'd use a more elegant solution. You've told me what not to do. Any pointers in how I can implement this properly?

Comment: Well, one benefit of using a hash is that you can print it with `Data::Dumper` to see what is in it. `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash;` This module is part of the core, and can incidentally be used to serialize data.

Comment: You can create your own simple parser for config files, if using a module is not to your taste (although as people here would say, you can always use modules). Use a file with tab separated values and read the file splitting on tab.

Comment: The only serialiser module that is in core is [`Storable`](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable), but that's a very outdated and awkward choice, if only because the resultant file isn't humanly readable. Do the *"certain modules on the server"* include [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON)? If so, then I recommend that you go that way. Or, if you prefer a traditional .ini file, you could look at [`Config::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Config::Tiny)

Comment: @TLP doesn't `use/require` also execute arbitrary code? I guess it all depend on who is meddling with what.

Answer (score -1):

How about this: read in component from @ARGV.

There are very likely better ways of getting the input but without using a module, this seems to work.

Put the value in a hash with the key.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $component = $ARGV[0] or die "no input"; #passed in as argument

open my $fh, "flowfx.config.pl";

my %flowfx;

while ( my $line = <$fh> ){
    # read in hash line by line, this assumes no useless input in file

    my ( $key, $value ) = split( /\s*=>\s*/, $line ); # extract key/value

    $value =~ s/\'//g; # remove quotes

    if ( $value =~s /\[/\]/g ){ # make a list
    $value = [ split(",",$value) ];
    }

    $flowfx{$key} = $value; # store the value in hash
}

close $fh; # close filehandle

my $info;

$info->{$component."_log"} = $flowfx{logfile_path};

print $component."_log".": ".$info->{$component."_log"};
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was obvious :) 
But how do I use a hash to achieve what I want?
As explained, I want to pass the component name in on the command line. So i DO NOT want to use the hardcoded value of $flow_fx{logfile_path}.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense now. Thanks for that. I'll give this a try.

Comment: @bytepusher: That is a horrible misuse of a file with a .pl extension. If you're not going to parse and execute the full Perl syntax then don't just open it as a text file.

Comment: @bytepusher: It also looks like you have posted and deleted comments that `@arkyc` has responded to. Please don't make a mess of comment threads like that: we can no longer see the context of those responses

Comment: I did not on purpose delete comments or the answer. From his post I assumed the file was as posted, I also wanted to show him a way of getting the data without "do".

Comment: I did not delete comments. From his post I assumed the file was as posted, I also wanted to show him a way of getting the data without "do", as ( rightfully ) commented by someone on the post. I find your comment neither helpful nor constructive